# android picasso not loading from intent getExtra

Tags: android, picasso

On intent, it's getting texts and but image is not loading.

My checklist -

- Checked layout IDs.
- Checked methods.

PhoneNo.class

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        PhoneInfo phoneInfo = (PhoneInfo) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneNo.this, SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PhoneNo.NAME,phoneInfo.getPersonname());
        intent.putExtra(PhoneNo.IMG,phoneInfo.getImgURL());
        intent.putExtra(PhoneNo.DES,phoneInfo.getDesignation());
        intent.putExtra(PhoneNo.PHONE,phoneInfo.getPhone());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

SecondActivity.clss

```
if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
    if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(NAME)){
        mPhoneNo.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(NAME));
    } if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(DES)){
        mDes.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(DES));
    } if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(IMG)) {
        Picasso.with(this).load(getIntent().getExtras().getString(IMG)).into(mImg);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `phoneInfo.getImgURL()` in `onItemClick()`? What is the extra'a value in `SecondActivity`?

Comment: PhoneInfo dm = new PhoneInfo("DM", "IAS Rahul Kumar", "+91-7634821504",
                "drawable://" + R.drawable.banks);

Comment: Either pass the `int` `R.drawable.banks` directly to Picasso, or change the scheme on your URL to `android.resource://`, instead of `drawable://`. AFAIK, Picasso doesn't handle the `drawable` scheme, by default.

Comment: Tried both. Not working.

Comment: `if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(NAME)){
                mPhoneNo.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(NAME));
            }if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(DES)){
                mDes.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(DES));
            }if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(IMG)) {
                Picasso.with(this).load("android.resource://"+getIntent().getExtras().getInt(IMG)).into(mImg);
                Log.e(IMG, "Log");
            }
        }`

Comment: Can you refer to any code??

Comment: `if(getIntent() != null && getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(NAME)){
                mPhoneNo.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(NAME));
            }if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(DES)){
                mDes.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(DES));
            }if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(IMG)) {
                Picasso.with(this).load("android.resource://"+getIntent().getExtras().getString(IMG)).into(mImg);
                Log.e(IMG, "Log");
            }
        }`

Comment: No, _change_ `drawable` to `android.resource`. Don't just add it to the beginning. Assuming `PhoneInfo` is just a data class: `...new PhoneInfo(..., "android.resource://" + R.drawable.banks);`.

Comment: [link](http://square.github.io/picasso/) It's loading images from drawable.

Comment: Yes. I did same way **drawable to android.resource** but it's not loading.

Comment: Hardcode is working: `if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(IMG)) {
                Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.banks).into(mImg);`
But TAG isn't working.

Comment: That's with the `int` `R.drawable`, like I mentioned as the first option. If that's what you want to do, then change it to an `int` in `PhoneInfo`, and change how you retrieve the extra from the `Intent`. Otherwise, correct the URI to one that Picasso handles. If you want further assistance with this, you'll need to [edit] your question to show your code as you currently have it.

Comment: `if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(IMG)) {
                iLink.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(IMG));
            }` This is getting R.drawable.banks but why image is not loading? Although it's getting through intent.

Comment: `getString(IMG)` returns a `String`. As I said, if you want to pass an `R.drawable` to Picasso, you want to change that field in `PhoneInfo` to an `int`, because an `R.drawable` is an `int`.

Comment: `public Integer getImgID() {
        return imgID;
    }

    public void setImgID(Integer imgID) {
        this.imgID = imgID;`

Comment: `if (getIntent().getExtras().containsKey(IMG)) {
                Picasso.with(this).load(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(IMG)).into(mImg);
                Log.e(IMG, "Log");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Picasso.with(this).load(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(String.valueOf(IMGID))).into(mImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this,

```
    Picasso.with(this).load(getIntent().getStringExtra(IMG)).into(mImg);
```

Answer (score 0):

change 
    `Picasso.with(this).load(getIntent().getExtras().getString(IMG)).into(mImg);`

into

`Picasso.with(this).load(getIntent().getExtras().getInt(String.valueOf(IMGID))).into(mImg);`

converted it to int since drawables are identified by int